# use enter alternate to key press in C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net

I'm designing login windows for desktop app, how can i use the "ENTER" key alternate to login button_click to let the user to enter the application after verifying credentials ?

Comment: Are you using Winforms or WPF?

Comment: The Enter key should always activate the default button of a dialog.  In Winforms you'd set the form's AcceptButton property in the designer, no code required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the click event fire on pressing the enter key, you need to make the button as a default button.

If you are using Winforms set the login button to the Form.AcceptButton Property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

If you are using WPF Set your buttons button's IsDefault property to true.